# Change html dir attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, right-to-left

I want to change HTML `dir` attribute once the page loads; how can I do that? Do I need to use the `.ready()` function?
Currently it looks like:

```
jQuery("html[lang=ar]").attr("dir", "rtl")
            .find("body").addClass("right-to-left");
```

How can I write it in a script; do i need to write in `.ready()` function or `.load()`?

```
<div class="header">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery("html").attr("dir", "rtl")?
</script>
```

The code appears like this:

This is my CSS

```
body.right-to-left li {
    float:right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: use it under $(document).ready

Comment: It seems you know the answer.

Comment: No, you don't need it. It should work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6c93/. Make sure the `html` tag actually has a `lang=ar` attribute. Of course you'd need `.ready` or `.load` to attach the class to the `body`. But what exactly is your problem? Is the attribute not changed? Is the class not added? Do you get an error? Where is your code located in the document? The more information you provide, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: every function that is in `$(function () {})` is called after the document has loaded.

Comment: @FelixKling my class doesn't loaded.. I can see my code in view source

Comment: @user1765876 View Source only shows the markup before JavaScript is executed, you should use debugging tools like firebug.

Comment: @undefined but I can see that it is ltr and through Inspect element I change it to rtl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple as it can be...

put your code inside...[document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("html[lang=ar]").attr("dir", "rtl")
        .find("body").addClass("right-to-left");
});
</script>
```

and a link that explain about `ready()` and `load()` function..

http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: It doesn't worked, I saw the viewsource.. but the html has still dir=ltr instead of rtl

Comment: can u post your html code where u want to change the attribute??

Comment: <?php 
if($_GET["lang"] == "ar")
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("html[lang=ar]").attr("dir", "rtl")
        .find("body").addClass("right-to-left");
});
</script>

<?php
}
?>

Comment: does your html has lang attribute... `<html lang="ar">`